# Python TLS socket: how to detect connection closed by server due to certificate failure?

Tags: python, ssl

Trying to write a TLS client using Python 3. Can't figure out what's the proper way to detect and handle connection rejected by server.

If the TLS server requires client certificate but the client didn't call `SSLContext.load_cert_chain()` or assigned wrong certificate, the connection will be terminated by server. The problem is, client side will not detect it until the next call to `SSLSocket.recv()`.

For example, the codes below will create a client TLS socket and connect to server and keep polling data from server:

```
import ssl
import socket

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = False
# context.load_cert_chain(certfile='client.crt', keyfile='client.key')
context.load_verify_locations(cafile='ca.crt')
with socket.create_connection(('127.0.0.1', 12345)) as client:
    with context.wrap_socket(client, server_hostname='example.com') as ssock:
        ssock.sendall(b'Hello, world\n')
        while 1:
            data = ssock.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                ssock.close()
                exit()
            do_something(data)
```

Suppose the server side is running in OpenSSL with `-Verify=1`:

```
openssl s_server -port 12345 -CAfile ca.crt -cert server.crt -key server.key -Verify 1
```

With the `context.load_cert_chain()` commented in client, this connection will be rejected and dropped by server:

```
ERROR
00A77D53F87F0000:error:0A0000C7:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:peer did not return a certificate:ssl/statem/statem_srvr.c:3511:
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
```

But the client side will not know this until fist call to ssock.recv() in `while 1` loop:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 13, in <module>
    data = ssock.recv(1024)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "***/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1263, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "***/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1136, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV13_ALERT_CERTIFICATE_REQUIRED] tlsv13 alert certificate required (_ssl.c:2576)
```

Is there anyway to detect connection closed by server before entering `while 1` loop ?

Comment: It sounds like you talking about detecting a failure in the handshake phase before attempting to `recv()` data. I haven't tried this yet, but you might try providing `do_handshake_on_connect=False` to the `wrap_socket` method and then explicitly calling `ssock.do_handshake()` just before starting the while loop.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk hmm… I didn’t set client socket to non-blocking, and SSLsocket.do_handshake() does not return anything, so it doesn’t really make any difference.

Comment: It doesn't need to return anything, it will raise an exception if the handshake fails, the same exception you got in `recv` when the handshake failed. And you should *not* set the client socket to non-blocking, that would defeat the purpose of calling `do_handshake()` and waiting for it to finish successfully or throw an exception.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Unfortunately, `do_handshake()` did not raise any exception.

Comment: It does raise an exception, I've tried it myself.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Tested with different versions. `do_handshake()` will raise exception in Python 3.9.6, but not in Python 3.11.4.

Comment: I tested it with python 3.11.5, it raised an exception.

Comment: Not raising an exception would be a critical security vulnerability, you should file a bug report with the python maintainers.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk updated to 3.11.5, no exception. It's the macOS HomeBrew release and guess I should follow your instruction.

Comment: @ PresidentJamesK.Polk After further testing, turns out its TLSv1.3 related issue. Force SSLContext to stay at TLSv.12 by calling `ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)` and `do_handshake()` will raise exception normally. Anyway I'd report it as a security issue.